# Hippomocks: How to expect only some of the arguments passed to ExpectCall()?

Tags: c++, mocking, hippomocks

In the mocking framework [Hippomocks](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/hippomocks/wiki) it is possible to check the passed arguments within an expectation. For example:

```
void Class::Method(int arg1);
...
m_mockRepository_p->ExpectCall(someObject_p, Class::Method).With(1);
```

Is there a possibility to check only some of the passed arguments? What should I write instead of ??? in the following code?

```
void Class::Method(int arg1, char* buffer_p);
...
m_mockRepository_p->ExpectCall(someObject_p, Class::Method).With(1,???);
```

For your information: The use case is that someObjet_p creates internally a buffer to read data in it and passes it to Class::Method. Firstly I don't care in which buffer someObject_p would like the data to put in. Secondly I don't have access to the internals of someObject_p to pass it to With() - which is quite reasonable.

Note: I've tagged the question as C++ as I make use of ExpectCall but I'd guess the same would apply to ExpectCallFunc for flat functions.

Second note: Hippomocks provides methods for expectations named "Match()", "getArgs()", "assignArgs()" and "matchesArgs()" but neither did I find any documentation on it nor do I know whether they are intended to be used (for my use case) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in a Don't-Care as that parameter:

```
m_mockRepository_p->ExpectCall(someObject_p, Class::Method).With(1, _);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer! Did I miss that in the documentation? It's very handy and makes Hippomocks even more useful!